# How does exactly rust handle return values

Tags: rust, runtime

I've got question about my code:

```
pub fn get_signals(path: &String) -> Vec<Vec<f64>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new().delimiter(b';').from_path(&path).unwrap();

    let mut signals: Vec<Vec<f64>> = Vec::new();

    for record in rdr.records(){
        let mut r = record.unwrap();
        for (i, value) in r.iter().enumerate(){
            match signals.get(i){
                Some(_) => {},
                None    => signals.push(Vec::new())
            }
            signals[i].push(value.parse::<f64>().unwrap());
        }
    }

    signals
}
```

How exactly does Rust handle return? When I, for example write `let signals = get_signal(&"data.csv".to_string());` does Rust assume I want a new instance of Vec(copies all the data) or just pass a pointer to previously allocated(via `Vec::new()`) memory? What is the most efficient way to do this? Also, what happens with `rdr`? I assume, given Rusts memory safety, it's destroyed.

Comment: Hello and welcome. If you haven't yet, I advise you to take a look at the book ([here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/)).

Comment: I think the fate `rdr` is a *whole other question*. In short: yes, any value of which the scope ends gets destroyed if it was not moved from. This means calling their implementation of `Drop::drop`, if any. And **this has nothing to do with memory safety**. Memory safety is not about leaking (or not) memory and other resources, it's about avoid dangling pointers and double-frees. Not destroying anything is a perfectly safe way to avoid dangling pointers and double-frees; it's the strategy used by the Clang compiler, and is the strategy of the [Java Epsilon GC](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/318)

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong. When the last pointer to memory dies, it lunches objects Drop::drop implementation if its present(?). So if the memory is on a heap it stays occupied? Can I allocate this memory later(is it available)?

Comment: I really think you should ask a separate questions here; or maybe check if the description of the mechanism is not available already. Comments are not that good for complex topics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How exactly does Rust handle return?

The only guarantee Rust, the language, makes is that values are never **cloned** without an explicit `.clone()` in the code. Therefore, from a semantic point of view, the value is *moved* which will not require allocating memory.

> does Rust assume I want a new instance of `Vec`(copies all the data) or just pass a pointer to previously allocated (via `Vec::new()`) memory?

This is implementation specific, and part of the ABI (Application Binary Interface). The Rust ABI is *not* formalized, and *not* stable, so there is no standard describing it and no guarantee about this holding up.

Furthermore, this will depend on whether the function call is *inlined* or *not*. If the function call is inlined, there is of course no `return` any longer yet the same behavior should be observed.

*For small values*, they should be returned via a register (or a couple of registers).

*For larger values*:

- the caller should reserve memory on the stack (properly sized and aligned) and pass a pointer to this area to the callee,
- the callee will then construct the return value at the place pointed to, so that by the time it returns the value exists there for the caller to use.

*Note: by the size here is the size on the stack, as returned by `std::mem::size_of`; so `size_of::<Vec<_>>() == 24` on 64-bits architecture.*

> What is the most efficient way to do this?

Returning is as efficient as it gets *for a single call*.

If however you find yourself in a situation where, say, you want to read a file line by line, then it makes sense to *reuse* the buffer from one call to the other which can be accomplished either by:

- taking a `&mut` references to the buffer (`String` or `Vec<u8>` say),
- or taking a buffer by value and returning it.

The point being to avoid memory allocations.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.
I'd like to stick to my case for a moment. You have said that large amounts of data should be prealocated on a stack. In my case function allocates memory dynamically on heap. I'm ofcourse aware of potentially many realocations, but at the moment I can live with that. My question here is: the way data is returned is implementation specific? For example, in Vecs case it returns `pointer, capacity, length`. So this data is moved out of functions scope. Heap allocated memory stays where it was. I cannot imagine if someone would do it other way.

Comment: @Kazik: Good point, I added a note that the size of interest here is that returned by `size_of`, so you are right that only pointer, capacity and length are copied here. Not sure whether those go through registers or stack. The heap allocated data indeed remains unmodified, actually, it even remains *untouched*: the pointer is not dereferenced as part of the move.

Comment: *"values are never cloned without an explicit .clone() in the code"* - Unless it's a [Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) structure, which still isn't quite the same thing as a `clone()`.

Comment: @BHustus: If it's Copy, then copying and moving are the same thing at the bytes level, so it doesn't matter :) Clone, on the other hand, can lead to deep copies... and coming from C++ implicit deep copies are a pain :(